# missing authentication for rest request elasticsearch

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

Iam trying to send data to elasticsearch, but when I am doing so, it shows that missing authentication for rest request elasticsearch. I did change the elastisearch.yml file :
xpack.security.enabled: false , but it is still doesn't work

Comment: did you restart your elasticsearch after making `xpack.security.enabled: false` and can you show the content of your elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: I solved the problem, I changed the licence in Kibana to basic and modified xpack.security.enabled: false and I did restart: It works now thank you

Answer (score 4):

The issue was the x-pack license, after changing the license in kibana to basic and disabling the x-pack security using `xpack.security.enabled: false` and restart it was resolved as mentioned in the comment.